# how to access array form position dynamically in html/php form?

Tags: php, html, smarty

I am doing a little learning on php and and html using smarty to aid it.
I am trying to build a very simple shop-alike list with a cart image that when it is clicked, it is supposed to return via form the info I want from that item, but I am failing to get the index of the items right....

This is the code relative to the loop inside the tlp (it is a HTML internally used by smarty):

```
{section name=i loop=$homeList}
     <div class="homemenu" align="right">
        <table class="menhome" border="0">
            <tr>
            <td width="102"><img src="{$homeList[i].img}"/></td>
            <td width="150">{$homeList[i].Nome} </td>
            <td width="350">{$homeList[i].Descricao}</td>
            <td width="80">{$homeList[i].Preco} €</td>
            <td width="80">{$homeList[i].Disponiblidade}</td>
            <td><form action="updatecart.php"  method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="usr[]" value="abobora">
                <input type="hidden" name="iditem[]" value="{$homeList[i].IDItem}">
                <input type="hidden" name="qta" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="index" value="1">
                <input type="image" name="submit" src="../images/carro.png" width="52" height="52"> 
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
{/section}
```

and this is the code relative to the "experimental" php update:

```
require_once("functions.php");
var_dump($_POST);
```

and this is a sample var_dump output:

```
array
'usr' => 
    array
      0 => string 'abobora' (length=7)
      1 => string 'abobora' (length=7)
      2 => string 'abobora' (length=7)
      3 => string 'abobora' (length=7)
      4 => string 'abobora' (length=7)
  'iditem' => 
    array
      0 => string 'it10' (length=4)
      1 => string 'it13' (length=4)
      2 => string 'it2' (length=3)
      3 => string 'it20' (length=4)
      4 => string 'it21' (length=4)
  'qta' => string '1' (length=1)
  'index' => string '1' (length=1)
  'submit_x' => string '22' (length=2)
  'submit_y' => string '27' (length=2)
```

The thing is: how do I tell the form that a single button has a singular index to the array and gain access to the correct info inside the array?

PS: the index="1" here is just an experimental value, what I wanted there is the info relative to the index

PSS: sorry for the bad output format, but there are times that I simply don't get how code tag works....

Comment: Code Tag Help - I just highlight all the code and click the button that looks like this {} on the toolbar ... just FYI

Comment: @dqhendricks because someone told to.... it wasn't my choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´m not sure I understand the question correctly, but are you looking for something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="usr[{index_in_array}]" value="abobora">
<input type="hidden" name="iditem[{index_in_array}]" value="{$homeList[i].IDItem}">
```

**Edit:** You are not closing the `<form>` correctly and that´s why you can´t rely on the index values that get sent in:

```
        <td><form action="updatecart.php"  method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="usr[]" value="abobora">
            <input type="hidden" name="iditem[]" value="{$homeList[i].IDItem}">
            <input type="hidden" name="qta" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="index" value="1">
            <input type="image" name="submit" src="../images/carro.png" width="52" height="52">
          </form>            // added
        </td>
```

Comment: in fact in the other php it is received as an array (as showed in the output sample), the problem is, in the updatecart.php I wanted the info relative to the array in the n element in that form, but the problem is, the id I get is always the last one. Something like: I hit the 3rd element of the list and in the other side it appears the info about the 3rd element (this means that the button "knows" what is the index value), but what I always get is the last element info

Comment: in other words, what it is supposed to happen is every form that I create can store it's index value independently from the others, giving me a selection inside the iditem array

Comment: OMG!!!!! That was the answer all along!! This is even more stupid than missing a malloc or free in c..... jesus christ.... many thx mate!!